# How to get folders in eclipse package explorer

Tags: eclipse, installation

I am new to eclipse and trying to get a folder in package explorer. For example a folder that drops down to three more folders for homework, lecture and labs which would drop down into the projects for each of those categories. I cant really figure out how to get it set up like this it only lets me open up one project at a time.

Basically looked things up on how to get it configured like that but not too many helpful videos or responses.

Comment: The top level in Package Explorer is always a list of projects, you can't have folders "above" the projects.